# convert a word doc to html and upload the html to a doc lib

Tags: word, html

I have come across a few approcahes but cant really under stand which one to use.
One is using the SaveAs method which i felt is the best of the lot. But i cant use this and upload the html file to the doc lib. Can anyone please help.

If it is unclear what my question is please let me know, i ll try my best to rephrase

Answer (score 1):

On a SharePoint Server a Service Document Conversion Service exists. This allows you to convert word documents to a web page in SharePoint. You won't have a html file but you end up in an article pages that you can then also edit in SharePoint directly. You will find more information in the following link.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-document-to-web-page-converters-HA010157537.aspx

Adding pure HTML Files to SharePoint is not so easy to handle because when you uploaded the html file, by default, SharePoint will force you to download the file instead of open it in browser. Therefore you need to change the behavior of the web application and need to change the file handling mode from permissive to strict. http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/sharepoint-2010-how-to-open-files-that-prompt-for-save-or-cancel/

Comment: Thanks stefan, appreciate your reply. But it is my mandatory requirement to convert using custom code and not OOTB. I have to make a html based on a template, so please can u guide me in this direction ??